Upload large files (more than 10MB) to onedrive via PHP, EDIT: try CURL, get only BadRequest
Hy there
I tried to create a php script, for upload files to my onedrive root directory, since 2 weeks.
EDIT: try it without sdk graph, but with curl
hy, it didn't work with graph..... so i try it with curl. now i get another fail, but the auth. works great.
here is the upload script for small files:
$createSessionUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/$fileName:/createUploadSession";

    $headers = [
        "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ];

    $postData = json_encode([
        'item' => [
            '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' => 'rename',
            'name' => $fileName
        ]
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($createSessionUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {
        return $responseArray;
    } else {
        echo "Failed to create upload session: HTTP $httpCode - " . json_encode($responseArray);
        return null;
    }

the fails:
Failed to upload small file: HTTP 400 - {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"API not found","innerError":{"date":"2024-05-23T12:04:53","request-id":"ea8707ae-5b1e-4092-84f9-7f429f85a270","client-request-id":"ea8707ae-5b1e-4092-84f9-7f429f85a270"}}}.

the Curl Request looks like:
cURL Request: Array ( [url] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/test.txt:/content [method] => POST [headers] => Array ( [0] => Authorization: Bearer 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 [1] => Content-Type: application/octet-stream ) [body] => dsfdf )

OLD:I use the github sdk, https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php.
I also tried to do it with the php tutorial from microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=1
but this ends, without a file upload.
So I searched here in the forum for a while and found something promising. Either way, it still doesn't work
This is the error message:
Uncaught League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException: invalid_grant
  

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;  
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use Microsoft\Graph\Core\Authentication\GraphPhpLeagueAccessTokenProvider;
use Microsoft\Graph\Core\Authentication\GraphPhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider;
use Microsoft\Graph\Core\NationalCloud;
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphRequestAdapter;
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Abstractions\Authentication\AnonymousAuthenticationProvider;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Cache\InMemoryAccessTokenCache;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\AuthorizationCodeContext;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\ClientCredentialContext;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Client\NetworkExceptionInterface;

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message;

use Microsoft\Graph\Core\Tasks\LargeFileUploadTask;
use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Drives\Item\Items\Item\CreateUploadSession\CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody as DriveItemCreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody;
use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models;
use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Users\Item\Messages\Item\Attachments\CreateUploadSession\CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody as AttachmentCreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody;

$client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4";
$client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxraqR";
$tenat = "common";
    
    //Authenticate
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenat . "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, array('form_params' => array('client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials')))->getBody()->getContents());
    $access_token = $token->access_token;
    
    echo $access_token;
    
    
    
    
    
    //ServerClient
    $tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext('common',$client_id,$client_secret,$access_token ,'http://localhost/test1/src/test3/test.php');
    $scopes = ['Files.ReadWrite.All'];
    $graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);
                            
    //upload
    
    
                        function uploadFileToOneDrive(GraphServiceClient $graphClient, string $filePath, string $itemPath): void {
                                // <LargeFileUploadSnippet>
                                // Create a file stream
                                $file = Psr7\Utils::streamFor(fopen($filePath, 'r'));

                                // Create the upload session request
                                $uploadProperties = new Models\DriveItemUploadableProperties();
                                $uploadProperties->setAdditionalData([
                                    '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' => 'replace'
                                ]);

                                // use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Drives\Item\Items\Item\CreateUploadSession\CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
                                // as DriveItemCreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody;
                                $uploadSessionRequest = new DriveItemCreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody();
                                $uploadSessionRequest->setItem($uploadProperties);

                                // Create the upload session
                                /** @var Models\Drive $drive */
                                $drive = $graphClient->me()->drive()->get()->wait();
                                $uploadSession = $graphClient->drives()
                                    ->byDriveId($drive->getId())
                                    ->items()
                                    ->byDriveItemId('root:/'.$itemPath.':')
                                    ->createUploadSession()
                                    ->post($uploadSessionRequest)
                                    ->wait();

                                $largeFileUpload = new LargeFileUploadTask($uploadSession, $graphClient->getRequestAdapter(), $file);
                                $totalSize = $file->getSize();
                                $progress = fn($prog) => print('Uploaded '.$prog[1].' of '.$totalSize.' bytes'.PHP_EOL);

                                try {
                                    $largeFileUpload->upload($progress)->wait();
                                } catch (\Psr\Http\Client\NetworkExceptionInterface $ex) {
                                    $largeFileUpload->resume()->wait();
                                }
                                // </LargeFileUploadSnippet>

                                // Added to remove warning about unused function
                                if (is_null($uploadSession)) {
                                    LargeFileUpload::resumeUpload($largeFileUpload);
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                            
    uploadFileToOneDrive($graphServiceClient, "test.txt", "test.txt");
    
    


Given the error message, it seems you're having trouble right at the beginning with authentication. What happens when you echo $access_token;? If it's empty, what happens what you print_r() the value of the $guzzle-post?

thank you for your help
the $access_token shows a string, like a token
and the guzzle-post shows a response.....
i got this:
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":86399,"ext_expires_in":86399,"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCx........"}

Good, you're successfully getting an access token then. When you see that error message, does it also mention a line number, such as /path/to/file.php:10 (line number 10 in this example)? That would help us determine where in the code it's running into this error.

thank you for your help
this a the full error message:
https://jumpshare.com/s/xw5dJuKVzO9DPJq9P387 
i need to share it as a txt file, because the message is too long

From that stack trace, it appears the error is occurring here during the get() method: $drive = $graphClient->me()->drive()->get()->wait(); So you're getting an access token, but then when you go to use it, it says it's invalid. That makes me think it's a permissions issue, possibly with that specific scope that you're wanting to use (Files.ReadWrite.All). Does your Azure AD app registration have that permission?

yes. it don't work... so i try it with curl
